# Do we need to manually start the Android emulator for Appium?

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

I'm new to appium and I'm running the calculator example test using the following code:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","AndroidTestDevice");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");    
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.calculator2");       
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Appium is running as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image]

If the emulator is not running, I get the error related to no devices found. 
My question is:

Do I need to manually start the emulator every time I need to execute a test? or Does appium will start the android emulator when the test is executed?

[image]

Answer (score 13):

<strike>In your settings enable "Launch AVD" and enter the name of the Android Virtual Device you created. This will start the emulator (if it's not already started) whenever you start a test.</strike>

Update:

You need to set the AVD capability. Simply add this line to your code `capabilities.setCapability("avd","AndroidTestDevice");`

Comment: I put the name AndroidTestDevice but it didn't solve the issue error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Could not find a connected Android device.

info: [debug] Error: Could not find a connected Android device.

Comment: Is ANDROID_HOME set in your path?

Comment: When I run the doctor, everything seems to be ok
Running Android Checks
✔ ANDROID_HOME is set to "/Users/moisessiles/Library/Android/sdk"
✔ JAVA_HOME is set to "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home."
✔ ADB exists at /Users/moisessiles/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
✔ Android exists at /Users/moisessiles/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android
✔ Emulator exists at /Users/moisessiles/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator
✔ Android Checks were successful.

Comment: oh sorry. it's because you're missing a capability. `capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","AndroidTestDevice");` deviceName is required but completely arbitrary for Android. if the AVD you created is "AndroidTestDevice", then you'll need to set the AVD capability. simply add this line to your code `capabilities.setCapability("avd","AndroidTestDevice");` I will update my answer.

Comment: This will invoke the Emulator and whether nthe Appium server would wait until the emulator is ready and also for the apk installation??

Answer (score 0):

Start it with `--apm` in the command line to have it start automatically.

Here's more info: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appium-discuss/SJGTD53Tj4o