# Appium - Timing out and Never got a response from command

Tags: appium, appium-android

We have UI tests to be started by Jenkins using Appium, but it results with an error:

> ```
> remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred
> while processing the command. Original error: Error getting AVD with
> retry. Original error: Condition unmet after 60063 ms. Timing out.
> ```

And there is no `emulator` process found when Appium's task is running.
Also Appium's output says:

> ```
> [debug] [ADB] Emulator Nexus_5X_API_26 not running
> [debug] [ADB] Trying to find Nexus_5X_API_26 emulator
> [debug] [ADB] Getting connected emulators
> [debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
> [debug] [ADB] 0 device(s) connected
> [debug] [ADB] 0 emulator(s) connected
> ```

OK, I see that device wasn't started and this is cause for the "Timeout" error.

But why Appium can't start it?

I'm able to get the `emulator` executable, and Jenkin's job which is starting Appium's task can see the device:

> ```
> [Pipeline] sh
> + avdmanager list avd
> ...
>     Name: Nexus_5X_API_26
>   Device: Nexus 5X (Google)
>     Path: /home/user/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_26.avd
>   Target: Google Play (Google Inc.)
>           Based on: Android 8.0 (Oreo) Tag/ABI: google_apis_playstore/x86
>     Skin: 1080x1920
>   Sdcard: 100 MB
> ---------
>     Name: test
>     Path: /home/user/.android/avd/test.avd
>   Target: Google APIs (Google Inc.)
>           Based on: Android 7.1.1 (Nougat) Tag/ABI: google_apis/x86
> [Pipeline] sh
> + emulator -list-avds
> Nexus_5X_API_26
> test
> ```

If I'm starting device manually just by running:

```
/android/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_26
```

And trigger Jenkin's job after this - I have another error:

> ```
> ...
> [ADB] Using adb from /android/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
> [debug] [ADB] Trying to find Nexus_5X_API_26 emulator
> [debug] [ADB] Getting connected emulators
> [debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
> [debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
> [debug] [ADB] 1 emulator(s) connected
> [debug] [ADB] Sending telnet command to device: avd name
> [debug] [ADB] Getting running emulator port
> [debug] [ADB] Socket connection to device created
> [debug] [UiAutomator2] Deleting UiAutomator2 session
> [debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1542807589908 (15:39:49 GMT+0200 (EET))
> [debug] [W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Error getting AVD. Original error: Never got a response from command
> [debug] [W3C]     at ADB.callee$0$0$ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-adb/lib/tools/system-calls.js:488:11)
> ...
> ```

Any ideas?

Can't even google anything with the "*appium Never got a response from command*" request...

Also, I'm not able to reproduce this issue on my workstation's laptop - all works just perfectly.

**UPD** Properties are:

```
<profile>
    <id>linux-emulator-8.0</id>
    <properties>
        <hub.url>http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub</hub.url>
        <device.name>Android Emulator</device.name>
        <avd>Nexus_5X_API_26</avd>
        <platform.name>Android</platform.name>
        <platform.version>8.0</platform.version>
        <auto.grant.permissions>true</auto.grant.permissions>
        <full.reset>true</full.reset>
        <no.reset>false</no.reset>
        <app.path>/home/user/project/project.apk</app.path>
        <app.name>com.gen.workoutme</app.name>
        <screenshot.path>
            ${project.basedir}/../screenShots/${platform.name}/${platform.version}/${device.name}/
        </screenshot.path>
        <automation.name>UiAutomator2</automation.name>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

**UPD 2** Not sure how - but not it works if run `emulator` manually.
But still, there is a problem with starting the `emulator` from Appium itself.

Found the weird error in its log:

> ```
> [ADB] [AVD OUTPUT] Fatal: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display  ((null):0, (null))
> [ADB] [AVD OUTPUT] INFO: QtLogger.cpp:66: Fatal: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display  ((null):0, (null))
> [ADB] Emulator avd Nexus_5X_API_26 exited with code null, signal SIGABRT
> ```

Can't google for reason yet but it looks like the main issue - something with a connection to the `$DISPLAY`, although it present.

Comment: can you show your capabilities?

Comment: @olyv Thanks, added Properties field.

Comment: is it maven profile?

Comment: you may try to add `avd` capability. For more info take a look at `AndroidMobileCapabilityType`

Comment: Yup. Did you mean something different?

Comment: I was referring to `DesiredCapabilities` but if those are only values, then it's ok as well.

Comment: can you add  in your capibilties  
  capabilities.setCapability("avd","AndroidTestDevice"); more info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34664560/do-we-need-to-manually-start-the-android-emulator-for-appium

Comment: @pankajmishra Will try, thanks. But I'm pretty sure it's something with the `QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display  ((null):0, (null))` error which causes the emulator to kill the device.

Comment: On Ubuntu, I had issue related to user permission. Changed permission using command `sudo chown -R <username>:<groupname> $AVD_HOME` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to start and run tests on emulator without any problem. I use following three capabilities along with other capabilities while setting up the driver.

1. `avd`: Name of AVD
2. `avdLaunchTimeout`: Time out to wait for emulator to launch.
3. `avdReadyTimeout`: Time out to wait for emulator to get ready.

Try using these capabilities and you should be good.

Also check if there is any updates for Android SDK and emulator. If there is update available, it's good idea to update it.

Answer (score 0):

Settings or python:

```
    options = UiAutomator2Options()
    options.avd = 'YOUR_AVD_NAME'
    # Timeout to wait until Android Emulator is started in milliseconds
    options.avd_launch_timeout = 25 * 1000
    # Timeout to wait until Android Emulator is fully booted and is ready for usage in milliseconds
    options.avd_ready_timeout = 20 * 1000
    driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub', options=options)
```